# How to create model for this json, c#

Tags: c#, json

How to create model for this json?

> {"code":"1", "message":"OK","response":
>   {"user":{"id":"124","usertype":"29","currenttime":"2013-04-24T08:09:20.487+00:00","sessionid":"2bcf1c92-9b97-47d8-8995-b39cf7cbe2af"}}}

I write:

```
public class BaseResponse
    {
        public bool success;
        public String message;
    }

    public class CreateTaskResponse : BaseResponse
    {
        CreateTaskResponseData data = new CreateTaskResponseData();

        public User getUser()
        {
            return data.getUser();
        }
    }

    class CreateTaskResponseData
    {
        User user = new User();
        public User getUser()
        {
            return user;
        }
    }

public class User
{
    public int id;
    public int usertype;
    public string currenttime;
    public string sessionid;
}
```

And parse:

```
CreateTaskResponse Login = SimpleDataSerializer.ToObject<CreateTaskResponse>(response);
```

error:
Login.getUser().sessionid is null

Comment: Are you using a [json](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) parser?

Comment: Consider using JSON.NET (I'm personally not a fan, but it seems to be the defacto standard for JSON in .NET)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I use Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) generated

```
public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string usertype { get; set; }
    public string currenttime { get; set; }
    public string sessionid { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public User user { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```